# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value using flexi auth library

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, datetime

Hello I have installed the library [flexi auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/) and I have a sql server instead mysql (I dont know if this change influence my problem).

When I insert a new user the query generated is :

```
INSERT INTO user_accounts (user_accounts.uacc_group_fk, 
    user_accounts.uacc_email, 
    user_accounts.uacc_username, 
    user_accounts.uacc_password, 
    user_accounts.uacc_ip_address, 
    user_accounts.uacc_date_last_login, 
    user_accounts.uacc_date_added, 
    user_accounts.uacc_activation_token, 
    user_accounts.uacc_active, 
    user_accounts.uacc_suspend, 
    user_accounts.uacc_salt) 
VALUES (
1
, 'user@email.com'
, 'custom_username'
, '$2a$08$KAFxZfqIDEOkucWAXePpYeQ6BiffjAxvTVv1HuXI3jgvBUo9OEHce'
, '127.0.0.1'
, '2014-10-21 12:01:18'
, '2014-10-21 12:01:18'
, 'faa46e2c45c383611dcb641f69e58144cc01962a'
, 0
, 0
, 'R4GC9hXyWW')
```

And the error returned is:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I think that is weird because the date have the format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

The description of my table is:

```
[uacc_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[uacc_group_fk] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[uacc_email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[uacc_username] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
[uacc_password] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[uacc_ip_address] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_salt] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_activation_token] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_forgotten_password_token] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_forgotten_password_expire] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[uacc_update_email_token] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_update_email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[uacc_active] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[uacc_suspend] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[uacc_fail_login_attempts] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[uacc_fail_login_ip_address] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[uacc_date_fail_login_ban] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[uacc_date_last_login] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[uacc_date_added] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Comment: do you specify any default values as the table doesn't accept nulls on any columns and you aren't specifying all of the fields in the insert?

Comment: Does this query work using SQL Management Studio? You may have a better error message when trying to execute it there, or you may have no error message, so you can look for the problem in another place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't directly solve your issue, a workaround and probably easier implementation of the `INSERT` is to remove the two `datetime` fields if you are just inserting the current date/time and use SQL Server's [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188383.aspx) as a default on the database fields.

> **GETDATE()**
>
> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset.

If you run this, you get the current timestamp:

```
select getdate() -- output: 2014-10-21 13:50:00.627
```

So you can alter the default of those fields to `GETDATE()`, something like so:

```
ALTER TABLE user_accounts ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_user_accounts_uacc_date_last_login DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR uacc_date_last_login
GO
ALTER TABLE user_accounts ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_user_accounts_uacc_date_added DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR uacc_date_added
GO
```

Or via designer:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This way SQL Server will manage adding the `datetime` values for you upon `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the Date format in use on your server, which is likely not YMD.
If I run the following in SSMS I get that error

```
Declare @MyDate [datetime] ;
Set DATEFORMAT DMY
select @MyDate = '2014-10-21 12:01:18' ;
```

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

While this works

```
Declare @MyDate [datetime] ;
Set DATEFORMAT YMD ;
select @MyDate = '2014-10-21 12:01:18' ;
```